# Leaflet Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I am trying to load map markers dynamically with leaflet and am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)

I am using this javascript to load my markers:

```
            var lat;
            var lng;


            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                lat = parseFloat(data[i].lat);
                lng = parseFloat(data[i].lng);

                L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
            }
```

My json I am reading is this:

```
[{"brewery":"21st Amendment Brewery","lat":"37.7824175","lng":"-122.3925921","breweryID":"EdRcIs"},{"brewery":"Abita Brewing Company","lat":"30.482408","lng":"-90.056605","breweryID":"BBE5WM"},{"brewery":"AleSmith Brewing Company","lat":"32.8924532","lng":"-117.1447157","breweryID":"ygAzC9"},{"brewery":"Allagash Brewing Company","lat":"43.702697","lng":"-70.317975","breweryID":"pdLPeS"},{"brewery":"Anchor Brewing Company","lat":"37.763487","lng":"-122.401367","breweryID":"6PBXvz"},{"brewery":"Anderson Valley Brewing Company","lat":"39.001384","lng":"-123.356081","breweryID":"L2dAEr"},{"brewery":"Anheuser-Busch","lat":"38.5986606","lng":"-90.208751","breweryID":"BznahA"},{"brewery":"Anheuser-Busch InBev","lat":"38.5985037","lng":"-90.2093428","breweryID":"BznahA"},{"brewery":"Asahi Breweries","lat":"35.709646","lng":"139.799797","breweryID":"tu8Rbm"},{"brewery":"Asia Pacific Breweries Ltd.","lat":"1.3361749","lng":"103.647081","breweryID":"AvTZ60"},{"brewery":"Ass Kisser Ales","lat":"32.729223","lng":"-97.415003","breweryID":"pqSkmD"},{"brewery":"Avery Brewing Company","lat":"40.016644","lng":"-105.218628","breweryID":"Jio9R0"},{"brewery":"Ayinger Brewery","lat":"","lng":"","breweryID":"QKdFk2"},{"brewery":"Ballast Point Brewing Company","lat":"32.7667586","lng":"-117.1952129","breweryID":"1d90Lc"},{"brewery":"Ballast Point Brewing Company","lat":"32.766785","lng":"-117.195246","breweryID":"1d90Lc"},{"brewery":"Baltimore-Washington Beer Works","lat":"39.167823","lng":"-76.5240722","breweryID":"dwroV3"},{"brewery":"Bass Brewery","lat":"52.8045853","lng":"-1.6281372","breweryID":"X2Qkw1"},{"brewery":"Bear Republic Brewery","lat":"38.6040452","lng":"-122.8599961","breweryID":"5tw2Iw"},{"brewery":"Belching Beaver Brewery","lat":"33.1450383","lng":"-117.2285575","breweryID":"rVzPCl"},{"brewery":"Bells Brewery, Inc.","lat":"42.2843486","lng":"-85.4538497","breweryID":"noGtDY"},{"brewery":"Big Muddy Brewing Co","lat":"37.7823381","lng":"-89.3321145","breweryID":"oBe8dQ"},{"brewery":"Birra Toccalmatto","lat":"44.866279","lng":"10.0615953","breweryID":"wAdTKf"},{"brewery":"Bootleggers Brewery","lat":"33.8682504","lng":"-117.933221","breweryID":"JQfyvi"},{"brewery":"Booze Brothers Brewing Co.","lat":"33.148172","lng":"-117.218047","breweryID":"xaBLno"},{"brewery":"Boston Beer Company","lat":"42.314449","lng":"-71.103365","breweryID":"1wSztN"},{"brewery":"Boulder Beer Company","lat":"40.0266779","lng":"-105.2479819","breweryID":"stdQLg"},{"brewery":"Boulevard Brewing Company","lat":"39.0821348","lng":"-94.5966532","breweryID":"VDMEV7"},{"brewery":"Brasserie des Franches-Montagnes","lat":"47.2542808","lng":"7.0025782","breweryID":"6DG1qh"},{"brewery":"Brasserie Dupont","lat":"50.5717946","lng":"3.6507079","breweryID":"o7aslJ"},{"brewery":"Breakside Brewery","lat":"45.571532","lng":"-122.6567911","breweryID":"bdjbTZ"},{"brewery":"Breckenridge Brewery","lat":"39.723597","lng":"-105.000614","breweryID":"IImUD9"},{"brewery":"BrewDog Ltd","lat":"57.64784","lng":"-1.934689","breweryID":"wfAwfx"},{"brewery":"Brewers Art","lat":"39.302771","lng":"-76.616387","breweryID":"YytkpO"},{"brewery":"Brewery Ommegang","lat":"42.6818046","lng":"-74.9254739","breweryID":"tCxPtR"},{"brewery":"Brewery Ommegang","lat":"42.6268786","lng":"-74.9452273","breweryID":"tCxPtR"},{"brewery":"Brooklyn Brewery","lat":"40.721535","lng":"-73.95745","breweryID":"4OBVPn"},{"brewery":"Brouwerij Artois","lat":"50.8870692","lng":"4.7025108","breweryID":"mIWMKP"},{"brewery":"Brouwerij Huyghe","lat":"50.99832","lng":"3.79404","breweryID":"8eyXN7"},{"brewery":"Brouwerij St. Bernardus","lat":"50.8425017","lng":"2.6362699","breweryID":"w9vR2u"},{"brewery":"Brouwerij Van Steenberge","lat":"51.176439","lng":"3.746045","breweryID":"shhuGO"},{"brewery":"Buffalo Bills Brewery","lat":"37.6738157","lng":"-122.0813029","breweryID":"P1I1gt"},{"brewery":"Burley Oak Craft Brewery","lat":"38.3338561","lng":"-75.2169099","breweryID":"rKXfsB"},{"brewery":"Butternuts Beer and Ale","lat":"42.6290648","lng":"-75.1854868","breweryID":"9BPs2d"},{"brewery":"Caldera Brewing","lat":"42.184409","lng":"-122.663147","breweryID":"iL3Juq"},{"brewery":"Center of the Universe Brewing","lat":"37.708939","lng":"-77.446687","breweryID":"B00bip"},{"brewery":"Cervecera Cuauhtmoc-Moctezuma","lat":"25.6375417","lng":"-100.2946801","breweryID":"UWBCmm"},{"brewery":"Clipper City Brewing Company","lat":"39.230827","lng":"-76.6751309","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"brewery":"Coors Brewing Company","lat":"39.759876","lng":"-105.219026","breweryID":"avMkil"},{"brewery":"Coronado Brewing Company","lat":"32.6977264","lng":"-117.1731838","breweryID":"gVynTw"},{"brewery":"Cricket Hill Brewing Company","lat":"40.872566","lng":"-74.296359","breweryID":"U0vh9j"},{"brewery":"D.G. Yuengling and Son","lat":"40.6999592","lng":"-76.1747169","breweryID":"pX8lES"},{"brewery":"DC Brau Brewing Company","lat":"38.929628","lng":"-76.960438","breweryID":"KRB0Bo"},{"brewery":"Devils Backbone Brewing Company","lat":"37.871161","lng":"-78.919124","breweryID":"iw1hDB"},{"brewery":"Dogfish Head Craft Brewery","lat":"38.770622","lng":"-75.310893","breweryID":"g0jHqt"},{"brewery":"DuClaw Brewing Company","lat":"39.496656","lng":"-76.329843","breweryID":"TVgBWg"},{"brewery":"Elysian Brewing Company","lat":"47.614033","lng":"-122.315716","breweryID":"hvWfx5"},{"brewery":"Erie Brewing Company","lat":"42.111185","lng":"-80.112978","breweryID":"LHQ79n"},{"brewery":"Evolution Craft Brewing Company","lat":"38.4622609","lng":"-75.5741469","breweryID":"Ysh6PO"},{"brewery":"Firestone Walker Brewing Company","lat":"35.595325","lng":"-120.693728","breweryID":"qghrkC"},{"brewery":"Firestone Walker Brewing Company","lat":"35.5954123","lng":"-120.6950281","breweryID":"qghrkC"},{"brewery":"Flying Dog Brewery","lat":"39.361926","lng":"-77.424677","breweryID":"jmGoBA"},{"brewery":"Flying Fish Brewing Company","lat":"39.912138","lng":"-74.970075","breweryID":"M5zcKb"},{"brewery":"Foothills Brewing Company","lat":"36.097341","lng":"-80.250882","breweryID":"ajREdT"},{"brewery":"Fordham Brewing Company","lat":"39.1540034","lng":"-75.4883626","breweryID":"D3A2mu"},{"brewery":"Founders Brewing Company","lat":"42.958468","lng":"-85.673516","breweryID":"Idm5Y5"},{"brewery":"Fulton Brewing Company","lat":"44.9849423","lng":"-93.2790206","breweryID":"5GoGSi"},{"brewery":"Goose Island Beer Company","lat":"41.887107","lng":"-87.6720969","breweryID":"APW1BC"},{"brewery":"Gordon Biersch Brewing","lat":"37.354139","lng":"-121.89286","breweryID":"P2xdU4"},{"brewery":"Grand Canyon Brewing Company","lat":"35.249954","lng":"-112.1891462","breweryID":"xcKkLh"},{"brewery":"Great Divide Brewing Company","lat":"39.753646","lng":"-104.9884698","breweryID":"I8WZv2"},{"brewery":"Green Flash Brewing Company","lat":"32.905722","lng":"-117.176517","breweryID":"Nj8cgD"},{"brewery":"Grupo Modelo S.A. de C.V.","lat":"19.422447","lng":"-99.209758","breweryID":"wadu38"},{"brewery":"Guinness","lat":"53.34309","lng":"-6.290799","breweryID":"HaPdSL"},{"brewery":"Hardywood Park Craft Brewery","lat":"37.5637197","lng":"-77.4603258","breweryID":"mftbkH"},{"brewery":"Harpoon Brewery","lat":"43.512997","lng":"-72.401527","breweryID":"RzvedX"},{"brewery":"Heavy Seas","lat":"39.230827","lng":"-76.6751309","breweryID":"wTFQaf"},{"brewery":"Heineken International","lat":"","lng":"","breweryID":"robMSl"},{"brewery":"Heritage Brewing","lat":"38.7523173","lng":"-77.4887259","breweryID":"LWv6MU"},{"brewery":"Hoppin Frog Brewery","lat":"41.0245928","lng":"-81.4677107","breweryID":"w5OOQ5"},{"brewery":"Innis & Gunn","lat":"55.951976","lng":"-3.211095","breweryID":"jC0TAa"},{"brewery":"Iron Fist Brewing Company","lat":"33.145823","lng":"-117.238546","breweryID":"hjb9rn"},{"brewery":"Jacob Leinenkugel Brewing Company","lat":"44.943321","lng":"-91.3953049","breweryID":"ZDghkK"},{"brewery":"Jester King Craft Brewery","lat":"30.233431","lng":"-97.995129","breweryID":"7kCNmJ"},{"brewery":"Kane Brewing","lat":"40.2368095","lng":"-74.0442545","breweryID":"XqWTM7"},{"brewery":"Karl Strauss Brewing Company","lat":"32.8320492","lng":"-117.2312344","breweryID":"mtUjck"},{"brewery":"Karl Strauss Brewing Company","lat":"32.832461","lng":"-117.2318045","breweryID":"mtUjck"},{"brewery":"Knee Deep Brewing Company","lat":"38.891802","lng":"-121.292128","breweryID":"iAJcs1"},{"brewery":"Kona Brewing Company","lat":"19.6419767","lng":"-155.9964298","breweryID":"8tlUI3"},{"brewery":"Lagunitas Brewing Company","lat":"38.272435","lng":"-122.662346","breweryID":"nLsoQ9"},{"brewery":"Lancaster Brewing Company","lat":"40.043733","lng":"-76.2980937","breweryID":"VGDfKl"},{"brewery":"Latitude 33 Brewing Co.","lat":"33.1362843","lng":"-117.2244859","breweryID":"GpPbOw"},{"brewery":"Latrobe Brewing Company","lat":"40.3197031","lng":"-79.3907376","breweryID":"MDO5n4"},{"brewery":"Left Hand Brewing Company","lat":"40.1587451","lng":"-105.1128246","breweryID":"Ro08YF"},{"brewery":"Lonerider Brewing Company","lat":"35.903672","lng":"-78.762493","breweryID":"d25euF"},{"brewery":"Magic Hat Brewing Company","lat":"44.428405","lng":"-73.213148","breweryID":"qIqpZc"},{"brewery":"Maine Beer Company","lat":"43.7057907","lng":"-70.3148766","breweryID":"xgrmyW"},{"brewery":"Maui Brewing Co.","lat":"20.972149","lng":"-156.677334","breweryID":"fwCFE4"},{"brewery":"Maui Brewing Company","lat":"20.972149","lng":"-156.677334","breweryID":"fwCFE4"},{"brewery":"Mendocino Brewing Company","lat":"38.9734335","lng":"-123.1162429","breweryID":"TR98tr"},{"brewery":"MillerCoors Brewing Company","lat":"43.044464","lng":"-87.962562","breweryID":"MWi5Kp"},{"brewery":"Moa Brewing Company","lat":"-41.542774","lng":"173.834236","breweryID":"McQx07"},{"brewery":"Mother Earth Brew Company","lat":"33.1682803","lng":"-117.2198359","breweryID":"NwFxny"},{"brewery":"Narragansett Brewing Company","lat":"41.8190249","lng":"-71.4097368","breweryID":"mGqkXE"},{"brewery":"Nelson Brewery","lat":"51.3943334","lng":"0.5297882","breweryID":"OYQA8m"},{"brewery":"Neshaminy Creek Brewing Company","lat":"40.085451","lng":"-74.902305","breweryID":"UbQHhM"},{"brewery":"New Belgium Brewing","lat":"40.593415","lng":"-105.066874","breweryID":"Jt43j7"},{"brewery":"New Holland Brewing Company","lat":"42.790315","lng":"-86.103885","breweryID":"AqEUBQ"},{"brewery":"Ninkasi Brewing Company","lat":"44.056855","lng":"-123.10988","breweryID":"V4I9FT"},{"brewery":"No Label Brewing Company","lat":"29.786632","lng":"-95.815891","breweryID":"4GJFCc"},{"brewery":"North Coast Brewing Company","lat":"39.446471","lng":"-123.806238","breweryID":"yLBNrD"},{"brewery":"Oak Creek Brewery","lat":"34.8663917","lng":"-111.7961404","breweryID":"9WPTNZ"},{"brewery":"Old Dominion Brewing Company","lat":"39.1540034","lng":"-75.4883626","breweryID":"xG9JyI"},{"brewery":"Oskar Blues Brewery","lat":"40.139056","lng":"-105.121887","breweryID":"q6vJUK"},{"brewery":"Oskar Blues Brewery","lat":"40.1390698","lng":"-105.1228796","breweryID":"q6vJUK"},{"brewery":"Pabst Brewing Company","lat":"29.4497864","lng":"-98.5386319","breweryID":"AKyyYN"},{"brewery":"Port Brewing Company","lat":"33.141417","lng":"-117.150076","breweryID":"ayEBYP"},{"brewery":"Port City Brewing Company","lat":"38.808003","lng":"-77.101365","breweryID":"9FwufS"},{"brewery":"Port City Brewing Company","lat":"38.8081958","lng":"-77.1014693","breweryID":"9FwufS"},{"brewery":"Refuge Brewery","lat":"33.5045422","lng":"-117.1585452","breweryID":"EswbVZ"},{"brewery":"Rinn Duin Brewing","lat":"40.123373","lng":"-74.24754","breweryID":"T90yOZ"},{"brewery":"Rip Current Brewing","lat":"33.1429833","lng":"-117.1925366","breweryID":"u2ExM0"},{"brewery":"River Horse Brewing Company","lat":"40.2763769","lng":"-74.796004","breweryID":"sYdp0k"},{"brewery":"RJ Rockers Brewing Company","lat":"34.948639","lng":"-81.935726","breweryID":"bWL816"},{"brewery":"Rock Art Brewery","lat":"44.557791","lng":"-72.608085","breweryID":"LpX3cU"},{"brewery":"Rogue Ales","lat":"44.620173","lng":"-124.0520565","breweryID":"X0l98q"},{"brewery":"Rough Draft Brewing Company","lat":"32.883619","lng":"-117.171625","breweryID":"gF2S17"},{"brewery":"Russian River Brewing Company","lat":"38.441415","lng":"-122.711872","breweryID":"BSsTGw"},{"brewery":"Rusty Beaver Brewery","lat":"38.0180585","lng":"-77.5151866","breweryID":"3RFxH6"},{"brewery":"Saint Archer Brewing Company","lat":"32.880493","lng":"-117.1631014","breweryID":"vOvOzV"},{"brewery":"San Marcos Brewery & Grill","lat":"33.134539","lng":"-117.190813","breweryID":"SEibYT"},{"brewery":"Schneider Weisse","lat":"48.91755","lng":"11.87451","breweryID":"FQLVgV"},{"brewery":"Scottish & Newcastle Breweries","lat":"55.954155","lng":"-3.202774","breweryID":"Qutakc"},{"brewery":"Shepherd Neame","lat":"51.3169414","lng":"0.8921279","breweryID":"c67gGy"},{"brewery":"Shipyard Brewing","lat":"43.6618784","lng":"-70.2489402","breweryID":"5N0usi"},{"brewery":"Shooting Creek Farm Brewery","lat":"36.907584","lng":"-80.218943","breweryID":"gop0Gz"},{"brewery":"Sierra Nevada Brewing Company","lat":"39.7246028","lng":"-121.8157154","breweryID":"nHLlnK"},{"brewery":"Sixpoint Brewery","lat":"40.6739317","lng":"-74.0119473","breweryID":"7VPQrN"},{"brewery":"Sixpoint Craft Ales","lat":"40.6739317","lng":"-74.0119473","breweryID":"7VPQrN"},{"brewery":"Sleeman Breweries Ltd.","lat":"43.4870365","lng":"-80.2067709","breweryID":"D61TcY"},{"brewery":"Smuttynose Brewing Co.","lat":"43.032502","lng":"-70.7947688","breweryID":"v0MKXA"},{"brewery":"Smuttynose Brewing Company","lat":"43.0323999","lng":"-70.7956193","breweryID":"v0MKXA"},{"brewery":"Somerville Brewing Company","lat":"42.402309","lng":"-71.120132","breweryID":"gwDTjS"},{"brewery":"Sonoran Brewing Company","lat":"33.448675","lng":"-112.016904","breweryID":"cuhBRm"},{"brewery":"Southern Tier Brewing Company","lat":"42.088931","lng":"-79.350342","breweryID":"x8kqVp"},{"brewery":"Spaten-Franziskaner-Br\u00e4u","lat":"48.14501","lng":"11.55419","breweryID":"o5vGy8"},{"brewery":"Spoetzl Brewery","lat":"29.434494","lng":"-97.166729","breweryID":"f35hQR"},{"brewery":"Staatliches Hofbr\u00e4uhaus (Hofbr\u00e4u M\u00fcnchen)","lat":"48.1373073","lng":"11.580357","breweryID":"4rlPFf"},{"brewery":"Stone Brewing Co.","lat":"33.1160006","lng":"-117.119811","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"brewery":"Stone Brewing Company","lat":"33.115682","lng":"-117.119552","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"brewery":"Stone Brewing Company","lat":"33.1160006","lng":"-117.119811","breweryID":"709vEK"},{"brewery":"Stoudts Brewery","lat":"40.2422441","lng":"-76.0540026","breweryID":"REDaIN"},{"brewery":"Sudwerk","lat":"","lng":"","breweryID":"bRKIdZ"},{"brewery":"Surly Brewing Company","lat":"45.04285","lng":"-93.324557","breweryID":"cPRfoj"},{"brewery":"SweetWater Brewing Company","lat":"33.808102","lng":"-84.38119","breweryID":"TMc6H2"},{"brewery":"Terrapin Beer Company","lat":"33.9804178","lng":"-83.3956826","breweryID":"DPLTAJ"},{"brewery":"The Bronx Brewery","lat":"40.80828","lng":"-73.930669","breweryID":"V0wvf7"},{"brewery":"The Bruery","lat":"33.8613833","lng":"-117.8800107","breweryID":"4MVtcc"},{"brewery":"The Duck-Rabbit Craft Brewery","lat":"35.600267","lng":"-77.597058","breweryID":"rBxNNF"},{"brewery":"The Lost Abbey","lat":"33.1416273","lng":"-117.1492671","breweryID":"9x7wNn"},{"brewery":"The Lost Abbey","lat":"33.141417","lng":"-117.150076","breweryID":"9x7wNn"},{"brewery":"The Saint Louis Brewery","lat":"38.632968","lng":"-90.209769","breweryID":"tNDKBY"},{"brewery":"Tr\u00f6egs Brewing Company","lat":"40.304","lng":"-76.643519","breweryID":"n5QFi2"},{"brewery":"Tsingtao","lat":"36.087509","lng":"120.34272","breweryID":"e2agAL"},{"brewery":"Unibroue","lat":"45.466125","lng":"-73.290924","breweryID":"llbEuB"},{"brewery":"Union Craft Brewing Company","lat":"39.331938","lng":"-76.641971","breweryID":"t6Gyij"},{"brewery":"Victory Brewing Company","lat":"40.0061038","lng":"-75.6941546","breweryID":"VoKbnS"},{"brewery":"Wells and Young&#39;s Brewing Company","lat":"52.132011","lng":"-0.481523","breweryID":"6oEP92"},{"brewery":"Westbrook Brewing Company","lat":"32.846477","lng":"-79.877235","breweryID":"HPfwPW"},{"brewery":"Weyerbacher Brewing Company","lat":"40.673181","lng":"-75.224926","breweryID":"a57dkm"},{"brewery":"Weyerbacher Brewing Company","lat":"40.673093","lng":"-75.225856","breweryID":"a57dkm"},{"brewery":"Widmer Brothers Brewing","lat":"45.540795","lng":"-122.675594","breweryID":"8wcv7h"},{"brewery":"Yards Brewing Company","lat":"39.962616","lng":"-75.136253","breweryID":"jwWiTH"}]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some pieces of your data have blank `lat` and `lng` causing `parseFloat('')` which returns `NaN`. The best fix would be to fix your data and avoid the blanks. If not, have your server-side logic catch those blanks. If not possible (because you're fetching from a third-party API or something), make your JS default to some number if it finds a blank string.